# Vim syntax defined folding transparent colour

Tags: vim, fold, vim-syntax-highlighting

I wrote Vim syntax highlighting definition code, and also defined folding.
Now I can use folding but when I have the folded line, I want to colour differently for the folding function part and the actual code

```
+--  10 lines: XXXXXX
```

So I want to keep the XXXXXX part still be coloured as the original syntax colour to stand out from rest of line.
How can I define transparency for the folding syntax?

Comment: Before I post as answer, pls try, if this is what you are looking for: `:hi! Folded ctermbg=none guibg=none`

Comment: Thanks for the help. That un-highlights the folded line, but doesn't give the original highlighting. XXXXXX is first line of folded lines which has highlights when unfolded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that currently isn't possible. There are two *highlight groups* that control the visual representation of folds: `Folded` (for the entire line) and `FoldColumn` (for the left-side representation of fold state). Likewise, "transparency" does not apply here; the *fold text* is a custom[izable] extract of the buffer contents. The real buffer contents are folded away, and not rendered.

I faintly remember patches that allow different highlight groups for fold *levels* or nested folds, but none of that has been included in Vim yet.

What you want to achieve would be very visually appealing. I see the following difficulties in implementing this, though:

The regular filetype syntax (that you want to apply) would have to match after the `+-- 10 lines:` prefix. Many syntaxes have elaborate containment or sequencing, and may fail to apply. Others may apply, but (because of folded away stuff), lose their regular context, so following lines will be messed up. This could be fixed with special syntax rules (maybe just including low-level stuff like syntax keywords and simple `:syn match`), but these would require the collaboration of each syntax, so hundreds of scripts would have to be extended by the various authors.

Comment: I see, I understand what I wanted wasn't simple. In my case, the syntax for the first line of folded group is completed by one line so I probably can leave the first line and fold only from second line, so the first line still remain to be coloured. Thank you very much for the explanation with details.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, folding from the second line only is one workaround. However, I would only do this if the first line really is "special" and highlighting is very important. Otherwise, if all lines form a single logical unit, folding all of them would still make sense.